Cleaning date column in excel where format not recognised
I'm trying to clean a date column in Excel and struggling having worked with Pandas.
The format in the column is generally of English UK type for example "25/10/2024" which is accepted by Excel as date.
However, data entered might be "25.5.2024" which isn't accepted.
Google Gemini says there is a formula called isdate() but not in my version of Excel.
I then tried =SUBSTITUTE(X2, ".", "/")
But that converts the string but returns legitimate dates as a 45058, for example.
I then want to extend it to deal with 'n/a' or blank, but the first part is confusing me
What do I do?

45058 is the numerical representation of date, you just need to format it like date - http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm#google_vignette

@Michal - that question is about parsing out elements from an existing date format. This is about a date format that is different and not being picked up by the interpreter in Excel.

"returns legitimate dates as a 45058" IS a legitimate date, just format it as such.  Please read the links above.

Following on from @Michal I used:
=TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(X2, ".", "/"), "dd/mm/yyyy")


You don't need the TEXT() function here. Once SUBSTITUTE() is applied just try to format the cells. Also are you aware that Text To Columns works for your scenario.
